# How to assign two fields data in header of react-csv

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, export-to-csv

I am working on `react-csv`. I created an array for custom headers there I used header array and assign `label` and `key`. Currently, I have a situation of two fields to be assigned ( in the header, `key` is used to assign the reference of data fields). I tried but I failed could someone please help me how to achieve this goal.

Thanks

**Code**

```
headers = [
{
  label: "id",
  key: "user.id"
},
{
  label: "Agent Name",
  key: "user.firstName + user.lastName"
},
{
  label: "Agent Email",
  key: "user.email"
},
{
  label: "Agent Phone",
  key: "user.phoneNumber"
},
{
  label: "Agent Commission",
  key: "agentComission"
},
{
  label: "Company Commission",
  key: "companyComission"
},
{
  label: "Total Sale",
  key: "sale"
}
];
```

`key: "user.firstName + user.lastName" },`, as you see I want to assign this two fields but when I click on export it gives me empty cell.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work

```
import { CSVLink } from "react-csv";

headers = [
{
  label: "id",
  key: "id"
},
{
  label: "Agent Name",
  key: "fullname"
},
{
  label: "Agent Email",
  key: "email"
},
{
  label: "Agent Phone",
  key: "phoneNumber"
},
{
  label: "Agent Commission",
  key: "agentComission"
},
{
  label: "Company Commission",
  key: "companyComission"
},
{
  label: "Total Sale",
  key: "sale"
}
];

data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    fullname: "name of agent",
    email: "test@gmail.com",
    phoneNumber: 123456789,
    agentComission: 'agent comission',
    companyComission: 'company comission',
    sale: 'sale',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    fullname: "name of agent 2",
    email: "test2@gmail.com",
    phoneNumber: 123456789,
    agentComission: 'agent comission 2',
    companyComission: 'company comission 2',
    sale: 'sale 2',
  },
];

<CSVLink data={data} headers={headers}>
  Download me
</CSVLink>;
```